# Weighted maximum likelihood estimation based on proportion of pipe at each age

Tags: probability

I have actual failure data of water pipe from 2004 to 2019. Based on the actual failure data, I have derived[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FLhQ.png) failures/km/year based on pipe age, length of pipe at certain age and actual number of failures.

I am looking to convert failure rate to probability of failure. Assuming that failure data follows weibull distribution, I am looking to derive shape and scale parameters to derive CDF or probability of failure.

Since the length of the pipe at 80 years of age is much less than length of the pipe at 40 years of age, Failure rate decreases as age approaches 80 years.

I would like to take into account the length of pipe at each age and derive shape and scale parameters that takes into consideration this factor.

Is there a way to solve this problem ?

I have attached failure rate per pipe age for reference

[Failure Rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FLhQ.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Where is the picture?

Comment: I have added sample data for your reference. Thank you for pointing it out.